# MVVM architecture with custom view

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-sdk-2.1

I want to make a custom view in android with MVVM architecture. First of all, I want to ask, is ViewModel working perfectly with a custom view as it works in case of activity or fragment? Can we get ViewModel from ViewModel provider in a custom view?

If I need to make a separate custom view what will the correct approach?

Comment: The Architecture Components ViewModels are made to work with Activities and Fragments, not with the lifecycle of a View, but if you want you can check these articles: 1. https://medium.com/@matthias.c.siegmund/mvvm-architecture-for-custom-views-on-android-b5636cb6be26 2. https://medium.com/@polson55/how-to-use-a-viewmodel-with-a-custom-view-403420f7aab4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q:** Can we get `ViewModel` from ViewModel provider in a custom view?

**Ans:** Simple answer would be yes you can !

But How? *(Further explanation)* **`ViewModelProviders`** required either **context** as `Activity` or `Fragment`. So you can retrieve `context` from your *CustomView class* using `getContext()` which would be `Activity/Fragment` where you're using it.

Cast that `context` to either of type & provide it to `ViewModelProviders` which will give you object of that `Activity/Fragment` container.

Hence using like this, you can share ViewModel between your `CustomView` and `Activity/Fragment`.

---

*Side Note: You can also make your `CustomView` implement **`LifeCycleObserver`**, in such way you can also make your view respect **lifecycle** of `Activity/Fragment` for initialization/destruction stuffs.*

Comment: `ViewModelProviders.of(context)` no longer exists in the newest version. How do I do this using the replacement (`ViewModelProvider()` that takes a `LifecycleOwner`)?

Comment: Yes, that's tricky now. To consume it via `context` you'll need to cast it to `LifecycleOwner` for `ViewModelProvider`. And on custom view, getting context will always be of Activity you're inflating to.

Answer (score 14):

A better alternative would be to use the new [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary?hl=ja#findviewtreeviewmodelstoreowner) `view.findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()` which gives you the viewModelStoreOwner(Fragment if view is attached to the fragment o/w activity)

You can create ViewModelProvider and then get the ViewModel.

Below is an example of code in Kotlin

```kotlin
private val viewModel by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        ViewModelProvider(viewModelStoreOwner).get(ViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Similarly, there are other similar APIs like `view.findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()` and `view.findViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner()`

It is a much cleaner approach as you don't have to typecast your `context` into `Activity` or `Fragment` and will scale to other implementations of `ViewModelStoreOwner` as well.

One thing to note here is that view may have a shorter life span compared to Activity/Fragment and so you might have to make a custom view Lifecycle(so that your LiveData subscription gets managed properly) using `LifecycleRegistry` based on `onAttachedToWindow` and `onDetachedFromWindow` callbacks

Comment: Note that these methods are only available after `onAttachToWindow()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
CustomView: ViewModelStoreOwner{

  private var viewModel: YourViewModel

  override fun getViewModelStore() = ViewModelStore() 

  init{
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[YourViewModel::class.java]
  }

}
```

In summary, this code defines a custom view (CustomView) in an Android app that implements the ViewModelStoreOwner interface. It creates and manages a YourViewModel instance using a ViewModelProvider, ensuring that the ViewModel survives configuration changes and is associated with the CustomView's lifecycle. The getViewModelStore() function provides a ViewModelStore to manage the ViewModel instances. This pattern is commonly used in Android app development to separate and manage UI-related data and logic.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Fairly sure this is just chat gpt gibberish...